# Pass nested object to component as props and then map the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have fetched some data:

```
const data = {
  type: "footer",
  company_data: {
    phone: "123456",
    email: "hello@site.com",
    page1: {
      title: "Terms & Conditions",
      url: "/terms-conditions/",
    },
    page2: {
      title: "Privacy Policy",
      url: "/privacy-policy/",
    },
  },
};
```

I use the component like this:

```
<Footer data={data} />
```

The component:

```
export default function Footer({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.type}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Great! This prints the type: footer. However if I try to map with `Object.entries` I get an error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {phone, email, page1, page2}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

OK so I can't use an object as a React child. I have tried converting to array using `Object.entries(data);` however, this still returns the same error as it's keeping the objects inside the array.

Any help on how I can get a useable array or object to use in the component with keys and values intact would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to print? You wanna print all the info from `data`?

Comment: yes, I can print single parts of it but I want to iterate through the whole thing

Comment: what are you trying re render?
you can't render an object, if you want to render it as a string, use `JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: why would you iterate over an object at all?

Comment: why can't you just access the required fields?

Comment: Data from a CMS, if they add a new page link it should update automatically.